# Flexible Nonmetallic Conduit inside wall?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, conduit

I’m finishing up wiring a sub panel in an outbuilding. There is an underground run of PVC conduit with THWN, which comes up to an LB on the exterior wall. On the inside I used flexible conduit so I could have a tight bend that comes up to the breaker box. Is this code? I can’t find anything in the NEC about this specific instance. I’ve attached a photo for reference.

I’m in the US (Florida). [image]

Edit:

The outbuilding is an office/man cave for me. I’m going to finish it with drywall. Currently there are 5 total circuits planned, each 120V: lights, a split A/C (20A max), and some 120V outlets. I don’t plan on ever having any heavy equipment out here, so there aren’t any 220s.

The feeder size is 6/6/6/8 (60A max). I’ll have a 60A double-pole breaker in my main panel and a corresponding double-pole 60A in this panel which will act as a main breaker/disconnnect. I know 60A is massive overkill. It’s a 120foot run and I wanted things to be as efficient as possible in terms of voltage drops.

That still leaves me with 1 open slot that I can’t really think of what to do with. I chose a smaller panel because I didn’t want to stare at a huge panel all day, and I just couldn’t think of any additional needs. Even the outlets could have really been consolidated into 2 circuits instead of 3, but I wanted the isolation for the computers/servers.

I hope I didn’t miscalculate. Am I able to use 2 of the slots in this panel for a double-pole “main breaker”, or do I need a box with a special slot for that?

Edit 2:

Here’s a photo of the bend and panel label. It’s fairly tight, but I don’t think it’s deforming the tube like it mentions in 350.24. I can measure the radius if that helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a close-up photo of the actual bend, and what size is the flex conduit itself?

Comment: Also, what make and model is that panel of yours?

Comment: If you need a main disconnect, Harper and Three Phase are the experts on this, this box won't work.

Comment: The make and model of the panel is an Eaton BR816L125FP. I’ll attach a photo of the bend and panel label.

Comment: So I just talked to the inspector, and it looks like another option is to just apply 225.33 (A), which allows up to 6 grouped disconnects, meaning I wouldn’t need a main breaker. I’ll probably still just use the main breaker and associated hold-down to keep it in place.

Comment: What size is the flex conduit, and what's the actual bend radius involved there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Liquid Flex May be Okay***

```
NEC 2017 356.1 Liquidtight Flexible Nonmetallic Conduit 

-- Basically says you're good but I cannot tell the size of the flex.
   It looks to be 1in. diameter, which is fine if that is the case.

-- You may need to secure every 3ft or less to be in accordance w/ 
   356.30 for securing runs longer than 6ft if that were to happen.
```

***However, you have other issues to attend to...***

***Disconnect Means Missing***

```
NEC 2017 Part II 225 Buildings or Other Structures Supplied by a
Feeder(s) or Branch Circuit(s) require a Means to disconnect all 
ungrounded conductors per 225.31

-- Basically anytime you have a separate structure fed by a branch
   circuit or feeder, you need a disconnect means AT THE STRUCTURE 
   to disconnect all ungrounded conductors (and no more than 6). 
   This is often done by installing a main-breaker type panel as 
   opposed to a main-lug which you have used as shown in your 
   pictures.

   The NEC does not define structure and as such a piece of wood 
   driven into the ground with a sub-panel on it could qualify as
   structure to the authorities having jurisdiction.
```

***Back-feeding breaker as a "Disconnecting Means"***

```
Per NEC 2017 408.36 (D) Back-fed breakers used as a Disconnecting Means
MUST be bolted or secured in place as to not be pulled out.

-- Basically this means you cannot just stick in a 60A breaker
   in you current panel and use it as a disconnecting means because 
   it is not bolted in place.  You could use a hold-down kit as 
   mentioned in your comment, but I think you'd do better with a 
   bigger main-breaker panel.
```

***You still need a Disconnecting Means in the outhouse in addition to the rule of 6***

```
Concerning your comment "...Apply 225.33 (A)"    

-- To be clear: Every structure requires at least (1) disconnecting 
   means but no more than 6 to disconnect all ungrounded conductors.

   225.31 has (4) exceptions to the location of the disconnecting
   means, but none are related to the rule of 6.
```

***Bushings***

```
NEC 2017 352.46 Bushings for PVC based Connectors &
NEC 2017 300.4(G) Insulated Fittings

-- If the feeder conductors are 6 AWG or larger you will need a 
   bushing for the PVC connector entering the bottom of the panel 
   box.
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the extra considerations. I’ll definitely use the bushing. I edited my question to include additional information that (hopefully) covers your point about the main breaker.

Comment: @JonWingfield I've updated my answer. Your inspector is wrong. Also using a normal residential snap in breaker as a disconnecting means is illegal too

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? A snap in breaker would require a hold-down. But if there is no "main" breaker, doesn't 225.33 allow the use of up to 6 disconnects?

Comment: @JonWingfield 225.31 requires all structures to have a means to disconnect all ungrounded conductors at the structure.  There are exceptions listed under 225.31 but none of those are related to the rule of 6.  The rule of 6 is totally unrelated.  It requires no more than 6 disconnect means per structure.

Answer (score 1):

Given the large size of the feeder you are bringing in here, that subpanel is very, very, very small.  *This is exactly what we warn people about: a situation where you run out of usable breaker spaces and now have to go to some serious expense or inconvenience.*

If you're thinking "well, well, I can just use double-stuff breakers and cram 16 breakers in this 8-space panel" -- not anymore.  Double-stuff breakers have gone the way of the dodo bird, as so many circuits do or will soon need  AFCI, GFCI or both.  Those breakers are not available in double-stuff.

The disconnect switch requirement will already force you to take this back to the store and get one with a main breaker.  Now, put in just a few dollars more and get a 16-space or 24-space.  Some of them even include "bonus breakers" as part of the combo.

Comment: Thanks so much for the extra advice. I asked another question on here before I started the work and I received similar advice. I’ve updated my question above with an explanation. I’m definitely open to reconsider since the walls are open, but hopefully I’ve made the right decision.

Comment: @JonWingfield That's what everyone does.  They go "I have all the spaces I expect to need *right now*” and so they button up the walls. Then something else comes along that they didn't expect, and they're like "Oh, snap, I could have avoided this with $20 extra back in 2019”... *Of course you're not expecting it... No one does.*